# ListBox.List Could not get the list property

Tags: vba, listbox, runtime-error

> Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation
> '-2147024882 (8007000e)'

I am receiving an error regarding List Property.  Usually this occurrs when there is only one option in the table.  Not sure what I am doing wrong :(.  My code is below:

The Error happens at xV = xLstBox.List(I)

```vb
Sub Rectangle2_Click()
Dim xSelShp As Shape, xSelLst As Variant, I, J As Integer
Dim xV As String
Set xSelShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
Set xLstBox = ActiveSheet.ListBox1
If xLstBox.Visible = False Then
xLstBox.Visible = True
xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Pick Measure Application Type"
xStr = ""
xStr = Range("MeasureAppBoxOutput").Value

If xStr <> "" Then
xArr = Split(xStr, ";")
For I = xLstBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
xV = xLstBox.List(I)
xV = xLstBox.List(I)
For J = 0 To UBound(xArr)
If xArr(J) = xV Then
xLstBox.Selected(I) = True
Exit For
End If
Next
Next I
End If
Else
xLstBox.Visible = False
xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Pick Measure Application Type"
For I = xLstBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
If xLstBox.Selected(I) = True Then
xSelLst = xLstBox.List(I) & ";" & xSelLst
End If
Next I
If xSelLst <> "" Then
Range("MeasureAppBoxOutput") = Mid(xSelLst, 1, Len(xSelLst) - 1)
Else
Range("MeasureAppBoxOutput") = ""
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Picture of an example of the table being referenced:

[image]

Picture of the error:

[image]

Comment: Please *indent* your code when posting.

Comment: When it errors what is the value of `xLstBox.ListCount` ?

Comment: Yeah, if you tried to get from `-1` to `0` by subtraction you would have to go around the world. It wouldn't make it because those would be invalid indexes.